# Не могу найти соглашение на использование платформы Google play services.

Tags: android, google-play

1. Её можно использовать в разработке коммерческих проектов?
2. Её можно использовать в приложениях, которые не будут распространяться через `Google play`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, разумеется.
2. Использовать сервисы Google Play (LVL, Game Center, IAP, subscriptions и т.д.) не используя сам Google Play не выйдет.

Comment: А Location APIs (Fused location provider) это касается, могу я использовать это API для приложений, которые не будут загружаться с Google Play?

Comment: Да, сможете. Оно ведь отношения к Google Play никакого не имеет.